# Output of cURL is corrupted when stored to a bash variable

Tags: bash, curl, newline, carriage-return, quoting

This is what console outputs when I execute cURL directly from the terminal:

```
/# curl -ksi http://localhost/ 
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Sun, 14 Jan 2018 11:49:38 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 160
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://localhost/welcome/default
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0

<html>
<head><title>302 Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>302 Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.6.2</center>
</body>
</html>
```

But if I try to save the output of the cURL to a variable the content of it ends up looking corrupted:

```
/# VAR=`curl -ksi http://localhost/`
/# echo $VAR
 </html>nter>nginx/1.6.2</center>er>d>fault
```

What is it that I am doing wrong in this case?

Comment: You are not quoting variables, that's what's wrong. Always say  `"$VAR"` unless you have a specific reason not to.

Comment: Quoting the variable should fix it!

Comment: There are probably carriage returns in the value, too.

Comment: @Cyrus  \r's are not a problem. \r's not followed by \n's are a problem. No quoting means all the \n's are turned into spaces. Just use the quotes to not let it happen.

Comment: @Cyrus why not ? Works for me.

Comment: @Cyrus may I ask you why the question is marked as duplicate? If I would know quoting variables is the issue I would probably search for "when should I use quoting?". The reason of downvoting is completely out of my understanding :) Well done community!

Comment: I didn't vote down.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array

```
var=( "$(curl -ksi http://localhost/)" )
echo "${var[@]}"
```

---

<sup>**Side-Note:** Don't use all uppercase variables like `VAR` as user variables  as they are reserved for the shell environment</sup>

Comment: The array will only contain a single element. It brings no value over a simple string variable.

Comment: I agree.. I was thinking about a specific use case, which in fact I saw in some answer in SO.. But I couldn't link it though.

Comment: thanks for the side note! The answer is not entirely right though, not quoting the variable was the issue

Comment: Indeed, but you got the point right?  :-) So all, good